# Add line for y value based on the max x value

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line off of a point in the y-axis based on the the most recent date. Ex. In this dataset, I'd like to draw a horizontal line at `y=38` where the `date` is equal to the most recent date (2013-12-15). This is what I have right now but it is not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z3CSn/1/

```
var recentDay = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date });

svg.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y1", yScale(recentDay.value));
```

Here is a mock of the desired end result:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23726217/line.PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, but there are minor two issues with your code.

1. When you are extracting the `recentDay`, `d3.max` is only giving you the date of the recent day, instead of the whole day Object. One easy way to get the Object is to just sort the dates, and then take the first one, e.g.

   ```
   var recentDate = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.date; })
   , recentDay  = data.filter(function(d){ return d.date == recentDate; })[0];
   ```

   I prefer this to sorting the `data` by the date and taking the first element, since this approach only requires two linear iterations through `data` (instead of an O(nlogn) sorting operation).
2. You need to include both the `y1` and `y2` in your line (`y2` is `0` by default), e.g.

   ```
   svg.append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "#000")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y1", yScale(recentDay.value))
        .attr("y2", yScale(recentDay.value));
   ```

Incorporating these two changes, I get the output below. Here's also an updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/6A4mb/).

[image]